# What's a tidy way to save all my workflow python packages for later, such that they all have their own setup.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.3, python-packaging

Python package directories seem overly cumbersome to me, I can't just have 1 self contained folder that is the package, if I want to distribute or locally install a suite of my packages.

If I read [the documentation correctly](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html), not only does each package folder need a second wrapper directory in order to be distributable, the official python docs actually recommend a third directory in between your `setup.py` file and your package directory.

So it looks like this:

```
my_packages/
  pkg1_wrapper/
    setup.py
    src/
      pkg1/
        main.py
        ...

  pkg2_wrapper/
    setup.py
    src/
      pkg2/
        main.py
        ...
  ...
```

Which seems really cumbersome compared to what it feels should be possible, something like this:

```
my_packages/
  pkg1/
    main.py
    ...
  pkg2/
    main.py
    ...
  ...
```

Do I have this right, or am I missing something?

Comment: You want to be able to install each package separately? Say, `pip install pkg1` one day and `pip install pkg2` the next?

Comment: The reason why the parent directory shouldn't matter is because of source control. Its `pkg1_wrapper` today but if that is a git repo, it could be `hack_to_get_it_right` tomorrow. The reason why setup.py should be outside of the package source is that its not part of the package. setup.py makes it easy to turn a directory into a package, but you could fill in the module/script/package references yourself and do it differently.  The reason for a `src` directdory is the assumption that your project will have other collateral. I don't use it personally.

Comment: @tdelaney I like the cut of your jib. Also, my work and projects have a lot of common tasks, and I'm finding myself copy pasting a lot of code and hating every moment of it. So I'm looking for a way to store commonly used python.. modules? Imports? Scripts? Whatever, and install/import them when and if I need them without bulking up my directory with a ton of generic files with more functionality than I actually need.